# Delete a whole word from a CSV file that is not part of another word using SED

Tags: text-processing, sed

I've searched for an answer to this and have come close, but not close enough.
We receive a CSV file that contains the text "NULL" which needs to be replaced by nothing. Example:

- Input

  ```
  12345,George,MCNULLMAN,NULL,green,NULL
  ```
- Replacement should result in:

  ```
  12345,George,MCNULLMAN,,green,
  ```

I tried this as a test, but obviously the word boundaries don't account for commas.

```shell
echo "MCNULLMAN,HELLO,NULL,NULL" | sed 's|bNULL/b||g'
```

Using `sed 's|NULL||g'` worked great for a while until we received a person's name that contained `NULL` in the middle of it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with tabulated data, I would recommend using `awk`:

```shell
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="NULL") $i=""}1' input.csv
```

This would set the input and output field separators to `,`. It then iterates over all fields of the line, and if they are exactly equal to `NULL`, replace them with the empty string. The `1` instructs `awk` to print the line including all modifications (if any).

If it needs to be `sed`, I would recommend to hard-encode the field separators (while allowing the preceding comma to be the start-of-line instead, and the trailing one the end-of-line):

```shell
sed -E 's/(^|,)(NULL)(,|$)/\1\3/g' input.csv
```

This makes use of capture groups to record the actual value of the preceding and trailing field separator (which may be the comma or start-of-line/end-of-line depending on which field is modified), and replaces the entire "preceding-separator+field+trailing-separator" combination by just "preceding-separator+trailing-separator".

**Please note** that this only works for "simple CSV" files where it is guaranteed that the `NULL` will not be quoted.

Comment: I'm new to the Linux world and know just a little about sed and nothing about awk.  However, the awl answer worked great!  The sed had an issue when I added NULL to the beginning of the string, but then that wasn't part of the original question. ;)

Comment: @aRBee Hm, that's strange. I tested the `sed` part also with NULL in the first field, and it worked in my case. Could you post the version number of the `sed` you are using?

Comment: I'm using sed (GNU sed) 4.5.  It's running in an Azure VM with Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.4.

Comment: The `sed` command would fail if there were back-to back cells containing `NULL` because given `|NULL|NULL|`, sed would consume the first `|NULL|` from the input as it matches `|NULL|`, leaving `NULL|` in the input which doesn't match `|NULL|`. That may be the issue the OP mentioned they had in the comments above. If you're going to use sed for this you need to do the operation twice - `sed -E 's/(^|,)NULL(,|$)/\1\2/g; s/(^|,)NULL(,|$)/\1\2/g'` so that `|NULL|NULL|` on first pass becomes `||NULL|` and then `|||` on the second. You don't need to capture NULL so I removed the parens around it.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to empty each field that is the exact string `NULL` in the header-less CSV input file:

```bash
$ cat file.csv
12345,George,MCNULLMAN,NULL,green,NULL
```

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N put 'for (k,v in $*) { v == "NULL" { $[k] = "" } }' file.csv
12345,George,MCNULLMAN,,green,
```

This will also work with CSV files that contain complex quoting:

```bash
$ cat file.csv
12345,"George
NULL,MacGregor",MCNULLMAN,"NULL,NULL","NULL",green,"""NULL"""
```

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N put 'for (k,v in $*) { v == "NULL" { $[k] = "" } }' file.csv
12345,"George
NULL,MacGregor",MCNULLMAN,"NULL,NULL",,green,"""NULL"""
```

In the example record above, there is only a single field that contains the string `NULL` only, and that's the 4th field (before `green`).  It additionally has a set of unnecessary quotes.  (The last filed is `"NULL"`, including the literal quotes, so it is not emptied. The first `NULL` on the second line is part of the 1st field, which contains a literal newline character.  Likewise, the field whose value is `NULL,NULL` is not touched.)

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{sub(/^NULL,/, ",");
gsub(/,NULL,/, ",,"); 
sub(/,NULL$/, ",")}1' file
```

---

Using `csvsql`:

file.csv as simple CSV file.

```
12345,George,MCNULLMAN,NULL,green,NULL
```

```
$ csvsql -H -I --query 'select * from file' file.csv | csvformat -K 1
12345,George,MCNULLMAN,,green,
```

---

file.csv with complex quoting.

```
12345,"George
NULL,MacGregor",MCNULLMAN,"NULL,NULL","NULL",green,"""NULL"""
```

```
$ csvsql -H -I --query 'select * from file' file.csv | csvformat -K 1
12345,"George
NULL,MacGregor",MCNULLMAN,"NULL,NULL",,green,"""NULL"""
```

- `-H` for `--no-header-row`.
- `-I` for `--no-inference`.
  Without this option the command changes `12345` to `12345.0`.
- `-K n` for `--skip-lines`. Skips first *n* lines.

This is used because `csvsql -H` command adds a header row. `- K 1` removes that.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -ne '.split(",").map(*.subst: :global, /^NULL$/ ).join(",").put;'  file
```

OR

```
~$ raku -ne '.split(",")>>.subst( :global, /^NULL$/ ).join(",").put;'  file
```

Above is an answer coded in Raku, a member of the Perl family of programming languages. The file is read linewise using the `-ne` non-autoprinting linewise flags. These flags instruct Raku to run the code that follows the flags over each line.

The input data (i.e. line) loads into Raku's `$_` topic variable. From here the text is `$_.split` on commas (note above: you can drop the leading `$_` and just write `.split`).

Next the resultant elements are `map`ped over to apply a `subst`itution to each. Here every match to `/^NULL$/` an element that starts-and-ends with `NULL` and nothing else in between is replaced with nothing (the `:global` adverb/parameter is superfluous but may prove useful in other situations).

Finally the modified elements are `join`ed together on commas and out`put`.

Sample Input:

```
12345,George,MCNULLMAN,NULL,green,NULL
12345,George,MCNULLMAN,NULL,green,nail
NULL,George,MCNULLMAN,NULL,green,neal
```

Sample Output:

```
12345,George,MCNULLMAN,,green,
12345,George,MCNULLMAN,,green,nail
,George,MCNULLMAN,,green,neal
```

https://raku.org